# MySQL average of non-null columns

Tags: mysql

I've kludged my way through by doing this, but I feel there's probably a cleaner/faster/better solution, and am always keen to learn:

```
UPDATE myTable SET fAvg =

(COALESCE(f1,0) + COALESCE(f2,0) + COALESCE(f3,0) + COALESCE(f4,0))

/

(
CASE WHEN f1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN f2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN f3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN f4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
)
```

So, how can that be improved?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the count by taking advantage of the fact the MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET fAvg = (COALESCE(f1,0) + COALESCE(f2,0) + COALESCE(f3,0) + COALESCE(f4,0)) /
               ((f1 IS NOT NULL) + (f2 IS NOT NULL) + (f3 IS NOT NULL) + (F4 IS NOT NULL));
```

Comment: If that's all I missed then I'm quite pleased - I assumed there would be some clever trick using FIELD or some multi-column-aggregating function that I've never heard of.